# Is it possible to create UISplitView only on one view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am creating an application wherein I have to create a master detail view (UISplitView) only on the second view. Rest all are simple UIViewControllers.

Earlier I have created IPad applications where I created UISplitView in the start of the application, but that is alive till the end of application. This is a different situation for me. So far I have not tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can `present modal view controller` in any point of your application. In that controller you can implement any type of `UIViewController`: such like custom `UIViewController` or `UISplitViewController` and etc.

For presenting modal view you can use following code:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```